# Load kext in recovery mode

Tags: partition, recovery, kernel-extensions

I've developed a kernel-extension and I'd like to load it in all possible modes which are Recovery-Mode, Safe boot and of course Normal mode.

When I stored my kext bundle In `/Library/Extensions` From normal mode, and then restart my machine and move to Recovery Mode, I couldn't find my kext in `/Library/Extensions` and therefore I tend to believe that Recovery Mode uses different partition.

My question is how can I access this partition from Normal mode, so when I install my driver, I can also place it where prelinked kernel can load it in Recovery Mode as well ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is quite simple just make sure you mount your Main drive in disk utility in recovery then make more of your Main drive name then quit Diskutilty and click on Utilties on the upper menu bar and then click terminal and to load your kext simply type `kextload -b /Volumes/Maindrivename/Library/Extensions/kextbundle` 
Just make sure you replace the command I provided accordingly.

Comment: Do you know a way to automate those actions to start the driver. I'd like to perform them on every entrance to recovery mode.

Comment: my driver is location in the main mount driver (meaning `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/`) but when I've tried to load it using kextload, i got : `failed to load - (lib kern/kext) not found` .. any idea why ? I also tried to load from `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/kextutil` but this tool doesn't seem to work on recovery mode

Comment: @Zohar81 My bad if the name of your maindrive has spaces then you ned to add a \ see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first answer is actually given by me but in a different account because I couldn't get access to my account. so first to run your kernel bundle using:

`kextload -b /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/kextutil`

And please do give me some time to load your kext in recovery too! Also this script needs to run as admin so you have to enter your password at login so I am still designing a script which will automatically provide your login password.